# print absolute path of symlink?

Tags: dired

Is there any function that can print a symlink's full path in `dired` mode? Alternatively is there any function that can print an arbitrary buffers' full path?

Answer (score 3):

`file-truename` returns the real path of a file and follows symlinks. You can combine it into something like `(file-truename (buffer-file-name))` to get the path of the file stored in a buffer.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Expansion.html#File-Name-Expansion

Answer (score 2):

Yes. this is lifted from [emacs-prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude)

```
    (defun prelude-copy-file-name-to-clipboard ()
      "Copy the current buffer file name to the clipboard."
      (interactive)
  (let ((filename (if (equal major-mode 'dired-mode)
                      default-directory
                    (buffer-file-name))))
    (when filename
      (kill-new filename)
      (message "Copied buffer file name '%s' to the clipboard." filename))))
```

Plus, in the most recent version, [neotree](https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree) has a function for revealing the full path of the node point is at: `neotree-copy-filepath-to-yank-ring`. I even have [this](https://github.com/ninrod/dotfiles/blob/57c8eac69132450f91907efff7f39846211e3d44/emacs/boot.org#ninrodneotree-copy-filepath-to-clipboard) on my configuration:

```
    (defun ninrod/neotree-copy-path ()
  (interactive)
  (message (concat "copied path: \"" (neotree-copy-filepath-to-yank-ring) "\" to the clipboard.")))
```